# RediSearch: OR union on 2 tag fields doesn't work?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redisearch

Hello I am new to using Redisearch. When I try to do a search on 2 tag fields with or union, something like

FT.SEARCH Idx "@TagOne:{tag} | @TagTwo:{tag}"

redis reports syntax error, apparently @Tag{} doesn't work of it is in front of '|' but it is okay when it is behind it. I can combine other types of fields with tag in a OR union, but there can be at most one tag field in the union, is it designed this way?

FT.SEARCH Idx "@TagOne|TagTwo:{tag}" doesn't work either. Is there a way around this?

I am using redisearch v. 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

please add parentheses:
FT.SEARCH Idx "(@TagOne:{tag}) | (@TagTwo:{tag})"